# WPF Custom Control with child ItemsControl not showing items

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I'm creating a complex custom control which uses both the Items property of the inherited control and also the `SubItems` of an additional embedded `ItemsControl`. Please find below a stripped code extract:

```
public class MyControl : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SubItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ObservableCollection<object> SubItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(SubItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SubItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyControl() : base()
    {
        SubItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }
}
```

And with the following Template (from Generic.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Items will be added dynamically to the `SubItems Collection`.

The control works fine in the control's constructor, the `SubItems` are set to a non-empty collection. For example by setting `SubItems = new ObeservableCollection<object>() { "" }`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: By replacing the ControlTemplate, your derived ItemsControl no longer displays anything from the inherited Items or ItemsSource collection. Besides that, it isn't clear what you're asking here. You say that the control works fine under certain conditions, but make no mention of what fails to works otherwise. What is your question?

Comment: @Clemens: The above code is a short extract from the real code, only meant to explain my question. By setting the SubItems to a non-empty collection in the constructor the control works fine and it is possible to later dynamically add items. However, if I set SubItems to an empty collection (like in my example above), any items added dynamically to the SubItems collection will not show up in my UI. I suspect there is some initialization/template work done by the ItemsControl to allow displaying dynamically added items, only if the initial collection is not empty at initialization/construction.

Comment: "I suspect there is some initialization/template work done by the ItemsControl to allow displaying dynamically added items, only if the initial collection is not empty at initialization/construction". There is nothing like that, and it wouldn't make much sense. You can of course bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl to an initially empty ObservableCollection, and later add items. There must be something else in your control (that you haven't shown) that is the reason for this strange behavior.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks for your comments. After realizing the fact that something else might be messing things up I found the mistake in another part of my code.